# How do I sent an int value from one thread to another?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

What is the right way to get an integer value back and forth between threads?

I have two threads running a run(){} function. One is receiving/sending USB messages and one is running a game UI. They both work independently. Modifying the value of the game with the data from the USB is the problem area.

What I've tried so far: I tried creating a global object called container which contained a public int variable and passing that to both the threads to communicate, but it crashes the program upon running.

Edit: Can I save the file to the SD card and have the other thread view it? Thread 1 will need to write to the SD card and thread 2 will need to read it. There is no need for two way comm.

edit: **If there's a way to create an application wide, global variable of type int, or an application wide object containing an int, that will work. If doing that exists, I'd like to do it that way.**

Comment: please provide your code and also the stack trace of the error

Comment: @christophmccann: How do I do that? I have to run the app on the phone connected to a microcontroller via USB, but I can't be connected to the computer via USB at the same time.

Comment: at least provide your code then...

Comment: If your program crashes, debug it. Unless you have some reason to think the design is broken, why change the design?

Comment: Global variables are to be avoided, even more so in Java.  They lead to poorly readable and maintainable code.  It is a terrible way to pass data between threads. Using a file to pass a value between threads is "hacky" and very inefficient.

Comment: Right. The shared integer should be associated with a structure that corresponds to whatever it is logically-associated with -- whatever thing both threads are working on.

Comment: Important basic point: threading in Java is generally not done by "passing values between threads", but by having "shared variables between thread". Other languages can have very different ways to deal with concurrency.

Comment: I'm more than happy to do it the right way. My problem lies in being an idiot and not knowing how to share variables between threads. Can you create a short example?

Comment: @user1018733 That's my answer below.  But you should read more about threading on Android; it's quite a complex topic.  In my example both `someUIelement` and `someIntReadFromUSB` are shared between the main thread (the UI thread) and the thread that deals with USB input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably stick to the Android threading model.  See  [this](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html) for example.

The UI thread is the main thread in Android.  *If your UI thread is not the main thread, you did something wrong.*

From the link above, don't use AsyncTask since you need something that modifies the UI more than once (I presume).  Call instead

```
myActivity.runOnUIThread(new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
       someUIelement.setValue(someIntReadFromUSB);       
   }
}
```

from your thread that reads USB.  When you declare that Runnable you'll need to have `someUIElement` and `someIntReadFromUSB` in the scope.  If they are local variables in that scope, you'll have to make sure they are `final` variables. (If you do have to declare the integer final, you can just declare a new final variable right before you define the Runnable and copy the value you want to send to it.)

Answer (score 2):

Use [AtomicInteger](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html).

Comment: There is no need that value is AtomicInteger, it is quite enough if address of value is 4 byte aligned!

Comment: @user1018733 If you make a reference to an instance of AtomicInteger available to both threads, then yes, both can use it and see changes done to it by the other thread (AtomicInteger provides the necessary atomicity and visibility guarantees).

Comment: @AdamZalcman Nice. How would I declare it in both threads? As long as it's the same name, the compiler will link the addresses of the two "local variables" into one global? Put Public AtomicInteger myglobalint; into both files?

Comment: @user1018733: if you are using only single reader than you do not need atomic value, as I sed 4 byte address value aligment is enough.

Comment: @user1018733 There are no global variables in Java. Are you using two Runnable instances? If so, create an AtomicInteger before you start the threads and pass the reference to both Runnables.

Comment: @G.J. I have no idea what you are talking about with your 4 bytes aligned.  Maybe it would work on an Intel processor, but it would most likely fail on an Android device with an ARM, VIA or MIPS processor.  He does need something that is well synchronized according to the Java memory model; AtomicInteger is one such device.

Comment: @toto2: We arn't talking about variable read-modify-write. So 32-bit data bus **ensure atomic write access**, in case that integer is shorter than 32 bit (4byte) and has 32 bit (4byte) aligned memory address.

Comment: @GJ Atomicity isn't all you need here. What about **visibility**? Also, there is no easy way to control memory alignment in Java.

Comment: @G.J.  Indeed visibility is a deal breaker here.  And as I mentioned, since this is for Android, the phone processors might not even be 32-bits.

Answer (score 0):

From

> "Can I save the file to the SD card and have the other thread view it? Thread 1 will need to write to the SD card and thread 2 will need to read it. There is no need for two way comm."

I think you could have a try of java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.

BTW, I know nothing about Android, but in pure java this should work.